# Get data from additional table in userstore during authentication

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I had to create additional table in tenant user store to store some specific data. Now I need to fetch data from this table during authentication in authenticator. What possibilities do I have to make a sql query to this new table? I know I can create custom user store manager, but it looks like overengineering to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can do this.

1. Write a custom authenticator
2. Write a custom user store manager

The above depends on the logic that you want to implement.

== Write a custom authenticator ==

Let's say you need to use these for username and password authentication. Then you can implement a custom authenticator by extending the existing authenticator. You can refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator-for-wso2-is-5-11-0-50332baf7668) for more details.

== Writing a custom user store manager ==

You can easily extend the existing user store manager and overwrite the auth-related methods to suit your need. You will be able to find many documentation and medium articles related to this. I would like to recommend this approach since this is related to the user stores.

Also, you can see whether you can achieve this using the Pre-Post listeners (If possible then this would be the easiest approach). During the user store manager auth methods, UMs fire pre-authentication and post-authentication methods. If you add a new listener and subscribe that to any of those events you might be able to achieve this use case.